# Change name of multiple files/folders under a directory

Tags: rename

There are some files and folders containing the word `apple`.

Like,

```
Root directory = AppleWorld
 ->AppleStore -> apple.png, appleStore 
 ->StoreOfApple -> apples -> peaches.png apples.jpg
```

I want to make all `apple` to `orange`

So the result must be

```
Root directory = OrangeWorld
 ->OrangeStore -> orange.png, orangeStore 
 ->StoreOfOrange-> oranges -> peaches.png oranges.jpg`
```

So, there should be at least 2 operations for `apple` and `Apple` to `orange` and `Orange`

I tried all `rename` commands.

For example these

```
find ./ -execdir rename 's/Apple*/*Orange*/' '{}' \;
find ./ -iname 'Apple*' -execdir mv -i '{}' 'Orange*' \;
```

but did not work. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method

- Change directory to the top of the directory tree, that you want to treat (change names of directories and files).

  ```
  cd top-of-target-directory-tree
  ```
- Then run the following commands, dry run to *check* and then *do it*, if the check looks good,

  ```
  find . -depth -execdir rename -n 's/Apple/Orange/;s/apple/orange/' "{}" \;

  find . -depth -execdir rename 's/Apple/Orange/;s/apple/orange/' "{}" \;
  ```

### Test example

```
$ find
.
./Apple3
./Apple3/Apple4
./Apple3/apple4.1
./Apple3/Apple4/apple5
./apple1
./apple2
$ find -type d
.
./Apple3
./Apple3/Apple4

$ find -type f
./Apple3/apple4.1
./Apple3/Apple4/apple5
./apple1
./apple2
```

Dry run

```
$ find . -depth -execdir rename -n 's/Apple/Orange/;s/apple/orange/' "{}" \; 
rename(./apple4.1, ./orange4.1)
rename(./apple5, ./orange5)
rename(./Apple4, ./Orange4)
rename(./Apple3, ./Orange3)
rename(./apple1, ./orange1)
rename(./apple2, ./orange2)
```

Do it

```
$ find . -depth -execdir rename 's/Apple/Orange/;s/apple/orange/' "{}" \;
```

Check it

```
$ find
.
./orange1
./Orange3
./Orange3/Orange4
./Orange3/Orange4/orange5
./Orange3/orange4.1
./orange2
```

Comment: Looks good - with GNU `find` you could use `+` in place of `\;` although how much difference it will make is debatable (it still uses at least one invocation per `-execdir`, IIRC)

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks for guiding me to this solution :-)

Comment: `find . -depth -execdir rename -n 's/Apple/Orange/;s/apple/orange/' "{}" \;

find . -depth -execdir rename 's/Apple/Orange/;s/apple/orange/;s/APPLE/ORANGE' "{}" \;` i used those and it worked. thank you both :)

Comment: @caneraydin, You are welcome. I'm glad that it works for you :-)